# Why tilesprite movement is not smooth in phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework

I don't understand why tilesprite movement is awful in Phaser. Sometimes the scrolling is smooth and the very next movement it gets stuck randomly, then starts scrolling smoothly again. Why does this happen?

Comment: provide some code sample please

Comment: in create method : `rtile = this.game.add.tileSprite(0, 584, 1366, 92, 'rtile')` 
in update method: `rtile.tilePosition.x += 40;`

Comment: there are alot of things that my cause that 

using canvas render instead of webgl

the texture of the tile is very large .

4 pixel is to big try to make it lower than that

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Chrome? [Check out this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422000) on the Chromium project. Essentially, there's a bug in the Chrome implementation of `requestAnimationFrame` that causes it to miss the monitor vsync and get into all kinds of trouble.

Try running your game using Chrome Canary; it's got the fix, I think... or, at least, my game runs completely smoothly with no issues on it.

Comment: i am using internet explorer 10

Comment: You could also try `this.game.renderer.renderSession.roundPixels = true;` to prevent sub-pixel rendering which can cause jitter, especially when moving the camera too.

Comment: I added it to game `create` function, the good thing is now the tilesprite smoothness is fair & greatly improved!! but the bad thing is now & then the tilesprite is giving choppy movement for 1-2 seconds.